# React - Redux - Electron app Routing

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron

I've just started my new project, which should be built using React,redux and electron, now I am stuck at routing problem. I wanted to use react-router-redux, but because it is not compatible with new react-router 4.3.1 I've decided to use only new react-router and not react-router-redux with react-router3.0, but I am not sure if this is good idea for long term. please give me any suggestions, thank you!

Comment: react-router-redux stores the current route information in redux.  react-router doesn't do this out of the box.  Do you need to store in redux?

Comment: good point,right now I don't need to store route information in redux,I thought it would be better if I wait until react-redux-router will be updated so it will be compatible with react-router and then I will rewrite my routing - if you know, can you tell me how hard this will be ,thank you! : )